# Amazon EC2 instances multiple IAM roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

At the moment I have 2 AWS IAM roles and each has 1 policy, call them Policy-A and Policy-B. I would like to attach both roles to an EC2 instance. Alternative is to create a new role which has both Policy-A and Policy-B.

Can I attach more than 1 IAM role to an EC2 instance?

Comment: You can attach only one role to ec2 instance. Refer this amazon document: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html. Instead create 2 managed policies and attach them to the same IAM Role. Attach that IAM Role to the EC2 instance.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can attach only one role to ec2 instance. Refer this amazon document: [IAM Roles for Amazon EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html). Instead:

- create 2 managed policies
- attach them to the same IAM Role.
- Attach that IAM Role to the EC2 instance.

---

*This post is a comment by [krishna_mee2004](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4191049/krishna-mee2004), but it should be an answer.*

Answer (score -2):

On Attach the two policies to one IAM Role.*(Updated Dec 2019)*

- Under ***IAM >  Access management > Policies***
- Create two Policies. [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_create.html)
- Under ***IAM >  Access management > Roles***
- Select the IAM role you want to attach the policies to

  - Alternatively Create a new  IAM role [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create.html)
- Select the **> Permissions** tab then **> Attach Policies** [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_manage-attach-detach.html)
- Search and select the policies you would like to attach to that role [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_manage-attach-detach.html)
- Attach your role to the EC2 instance [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html#attach-iam-role) .

> On the navigation pane, choose ***> Instances.***
>
> Select the instance, ***choose Actions > Instance Settings> Attach/Replace
>   IAM role***.

**References:**

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_create.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_manage-attach-detach.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html#attach-iam-role

Comment: I can't see how to attach a role to a group. Do you do it via the roles menu or groups menu? I've only been able to attach users to groups.

Comment: I can't see how to attach a group to an ec2 instance as a role. When I choose "Attach/Replace IAM Role", I only get an option of picking a role, not a group.

Comment: There is no option to add a role to a group.